# How to check if a line from txt file startswith "h" in android?

Tags: java, android, line

I'm developing a Livestream app which supports a MaterialFileChooser, but I'm struggling to check if a line from the chosen text file starts with "h" the lines (that start with h) should be stored in a string.

I tried this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1000 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String filePath = data.getStringExtra(FilePickerActivity.RESULT_FILE_PATH);

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
               if (line.startsWith("h")) {
                   // Confusion
               }
            }

            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the confusion you are referring to? What are you expecting and what do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand what do you mean by "should be stored in a string". If you need the line that starts with "h" just create an `ArrayList` of strings and save it there.

```
// Declare an ArrayList first 
private ArrayList<String> lineStore = new ArrayList<String>();

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1000 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String filePath = data.getStringExtra(FilePickerActivity.RESULT_FILE_PATH);

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
               if (line.startsWith("h")) {
                   // Store the line in the ArrayList to be used later
                   lineStore.add(line); // That's what you meant? 
               }
            }

            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes exactly that's what I meant thank you for the reply !

Comment: Great to know that helped!